# Is there a javascript equivalent of the Multimap data structure?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, multimap

[Multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) is an data structure that maps a key to a list/set of values.

Is there a good, unobtrusive js library that implements this data structure?

**Edit** - I know I can implement it "easily" myself, but I believe having it as a standalone abstraction is a good thing, so answers to this questions should not be "just implement it yourself".

Comment: You may try to use [**multimap.js**](http://code.google.com/p/backplanejs/source/browse/third-party/uxf/src/lib/_backplane/multimap.js?r=e436949ff2516d2c15fbd8d31f5da7744ed5cb93).

Comment: Object that has arrays as values?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Should be adapted as it requires `UX.Class`.

Comment: + toss in [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), and you're good to go!

Comment: @Esailija, in Java you can use `Map<Key, List<Value>>`, but someone obviously thought multimap is important enough to code it in Java. Why not JS? http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: In line with `Map<Key, List<Value>>`, you can use a `Map` with `Array` values in newer JS environments, or a `Map` with `Set` values if you want to ignore duplicates.

Comment: You can make your own MultiMap in es2015 by extending Map. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/johnsonjo4531/j5zjchmb/1/. Note babel doesn't support extending builtins so you'll just have to deal with the support that es2015 has.

Answer (score 3):

Since @Esailija posted this as a comment only, I'll submit it as a possible answer. Objects using arrays as values is the way to go, and manipulate the values by way of [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
var map = {
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: ['1', '2', '3']
};

map.foo = _.union(map.foo, [1, 4]); // map.foo -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

While it obviously depends on your needs, this approach gives you generic data structures that goes everywhere, and a library that works very nicely with collections and lists. For most purposes, performance of this approach should be just fine (just don't do it millions of times each second).

Comment: See my comment: the ability to implement it using a List and an Array is not an excuse not to have a "go-to" multimap class. Sure, I might use this instead of writing one from scratch, but if a library I was already using (e.g. jQuery) had a multimap class, I'd rather use that than play with arrays myself.